# Select com dois campos como FKs de uma mesma tabela

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu gostaria de saber como montar um `select` em Oracle para realizar a saída dos nomes dos times que participaram de um jogo, utilizando a estrutura abaixo:

[image: Estrutura das tabelas]

Segue o código para criação da tabela: [Código para criação da tabela](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MQHq-LmPrdKuh64wUmzvVi9elusoZBIJ/view?usp=sharing)

Penso que a saída seria algo do tipo:

```
Código do Jogo | Nome do Time 1 | Nome do Time 2 | Data do Jogo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer dois *joins* para a mesma tabela de times, usando *aliases* diferentes, vinculando um *join* ao campo de identificação do time 1 e o outro ao campo de identificação do time 2, na tabela de jogos:

```sql
select
  j.A_CODIGO_JOGO_PK AS "Código do Jogo",
  j.A_DATA_JOGO AS "Data do Jogo",
  t1.A_NOME_TIME AS "Nome do Time 1",
  t2.A_NOME_TIME AS "Nome do Time 2"
from T_JOGO j
inner join T_TIME t1 on t1.A_CODIGO_TIME_PK = j.A_CODIGO_TIME1_FK
inner join T_TIME t2 on t2.A_CODIGO_TIME_PK = j.A_CODIGO_TIME2_FK
```

Veja o código funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a3b84/1/0).